# Angular custom service is called in infinite loop

Tags: angular

I am new to `Angular`, but I have to modify existing code.

The idea is that there is a flag (`showFeature`). Previously, it was just static boolean value, however now it is more complicated.

```
  @Input() isAccepted: boolean;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
  ...

  showFeature() {
    this.myService.showFlagPromise().then((isOn: boolean) => {
      return (this.isAccepted === true) && isOn
    });
    return true;
  }
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
  

  }

  showFlagPromise() {
    return this.http.get<boolean>("/showFlagPromise").toPromise();
  }
}
```

HTML for this:

```
 <div [hidden]="!showFeature()"> Some button here </div>
```

Here I have a problem that call to `this.myService.showFlagPromise` is done infinitely. There is infinite calls to backend API. I understand that this is because each time Angular tries to updated value of `showFeature` that is used in `html` to show or hide some part of code.

What is the right way to fix it?

Comment: Please share also your template (html) so we can see who's calling what.

Comment: I have added small html code

Answer (score 1):

```
@Input() isAccepted: boolean;
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
  ...

  showFlag : boolean = false;

  showFeature() {
    this.myService.showFlagPromise().then((isOn: boolean) => {
      this.showFlag = (this.isAccepted === true) && isOn;
    });
  }
```

Then bind your html only to this variable showFlag which by default will be false just to be safe. So by default it will not show anything and when the backend returns if it must show this flag then it will be shown.

Also Invoke showFeature() when you make any changes or when your html loads in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 1):

you have two way to do that.

1. create interval method for call your showFeature function like this :

   ```
   this.timer = setInterval(() => {
     this.showFeature();
   }, 2000);

   ngOnDestroy() {
     //do not forgot to clear interval
     clearInterval(this.timer);
   }
   ```
2. go for websocket implementation and get that data streamly form your backend API (recommend)